# Terraform: How can I read variables into Terraform from a YAML file? Or from a DB like Hiera?

Tags: terraform

I wanted to read variables into my Terraform configuration file from an external YAML file or from a database like Hiera, how can I do that? For example:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = hiera('virginia')    # this should look up for virginia=us-east-1
}

resource "aws_instance" {
    ami = hiera('production') 
    ....
    ....
}
```

Basically its similar to how we can do a lookup for Puppet manifests/configs using hiera or a YAML file.

Comment: You need to develop that provider by yourself, or write a wrapper script to read the yaml and feed as TF_VAR_ <variable>, such as `TF_VAR_virginia`

Comment: one of many options would be to use Ansible to read from your YML file and replace the values in your Terraform file(s).

Comment: @Steven do you have an example of that?

Comment: just wontering, why do you want to read from yaml files? why not to use the default methods?

Answer (score 29):

`yamldecode` function can be use to read Yaml file as input for terraform and parse it to use.

Let's say test.yml file as below

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
```

Then below code can be use to read the yaml file

```
output "log" {
  value = "${yamldecode(file("test.yml"))}"
}
```

In order to parse a specific value read from a yaml file

```
output "log" {
  value = "${yamldecode(file("test.yml"))["a"]}"
}
```

**Important**: this is available in 0.12 or later version of terraform, in case of using the old version of terraform and still want to use yaml file, then use [terraform-provider-yaml](https://github.com/ashald/terraform-provider-yaml)

Comment: indeed, we can use csvdecode to read csv file.

Comment: What about the validation of variables?

Answer (score 7):

You can include the yaml file as a [local](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals):

```
locals {
  config  = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/configfile.yml"))
}
```

Now you can call all variables from `local.config`, for example a variable `project_name`:

```
local.config.project_name
```

Comment: This ignores that variables may have validation logic.

Answer (score -7):

You have to move the variables to a terraform.tfvars or a *.auto.tfvars file.

https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files

> To persist variable values, create a file and assign variables within
> this file. Create a file named terraform.tfvars with the following
> contents:
>
> access_key = "foo"
>
> secret_key = "bar"
>
> For all files which match terraform.tfvars or *.auto.tfvars present in
> the current directory, Terraform automatically loads them to populate
> variables. If the file is named something else, you can use the
> -var-file flag directly to specify a file. These files are the same syntax as Terraform configuration files. And like Terraform
> configuration files, these files can also be JSON.

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the question.

Comment: It almost answers the question because the "these files can also be JSON" not quite yaml, but it helps me.

The other answer doesn't help me because I need to apply a validation block to the input.

I'm think of having a makefile that turns the yaml into json. Horrible but the best I have so far ;)